# Why is LogTicks incorrect?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, scidraw

It is a simple example using `CustomTicks` package:

```
<< CustomTicks`

Show[LogPlot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}], Ticks -> {Automatic, LogTicks}]
```

but we can see on the picture that the `LogTicks` on the vertical axis are not correct for `x^2`. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Incorrect logticks on the vertical axis]

Comment: The ticks are being processed twice, once by LogPlot and once by LogTicks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest fix is do the `Log` yourself:

```
Show[Plot[Log10[x^2], {x, 0, 10}], Ticks -> {Automatic, LogTicks}]
```

[image]

Note that the documentation says that you can also use

```
SetOptions[LogTicks, LogPlot -> True];
```

but it doesn't seem to work straight-forwardly.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer!