# SciDraw/CustomTicks: LogTicks with LogPlot->True produces tick labels with errant decimal points

Tags: plotting, ticks, scidraw

Using SciDraw (for customTicks), when I set

```
SetOptions[LogTicks, LogPlot -> True]
```

I get errant behavior. When LogTicks *does* work for LogPlots/LogLogPlots, as it does for

```
ListLogLogPlot[Table[{10^-x, 10^-x}, {x, 1, 5}], Frame -> True, Joined -> True, FrameTicks -> {{LogTicks, None}, {LogTicks, None}}]
```

what's produced has tick labels of the form 10.<sup>-5.</sup>, i.e. with decimal points:

[image]

(The decimals aren't present when `LogPot->False`.)
Other attempts to `LogPlot` with `LogTicks` and the aforementioned settings do not work at all. If I try to run `LogTicks[10,-1,1]`, the output returns many errors:

[image]

I've been trying to find a way to remove the decimal points I showed above with `NumberPoint -> ""`, to no avail. (LogTicks won't accept it as an option, though the documentation seems to indicate it should.) But it seems clear the problem runs deeper than that. I am hoping to use `LogTicks` as in my first example, because 1) I run into plot range issues when manually taking the `Log10` of my data and 2) I would like the tick labels to automatically generate, i.e. so that I don't have to choose the range, spacing, etc.

Edit: wrapping the plot function in `Style[...,NumberPoint->""]` seems to do the trick for my first example. But a resolution to the other issues would be appreciated.

Comment: `LogPlot -> True` seems to be buggy, I agree. I suggest plotting the log instead, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137949/38410